# MYSQL select student_id if cleared status is equal to one

Tags: php, mysql

Table name : batch_1_student_marks

i am having student mark list in batch_1_student_marks table.

where "cleared" is representing the student pass/fail status. 
 cleared = 1 (pass) 
 cleared = 0 (fail)

In the following table student_id 2 is only having cleared status 1 in all rows. i dont want to select student_id 1 and 3 because it having cleared status 0 in corresponding rows.

if i use the following query it will give the result, 
SELECT student_id from batch_1_student_marks WHERE student_id=2 and cleared=1. 
but this query is not suitable for student_id 1 and 3. because i dont want to select student_id if it has cleared 0 in even single row.........
please help me to do a query...

|id|  |semester|  |student_id|  |subject_id|  |grade| |marks| |cleared| 
1  -----1 --------------1-------------1-----------a---------8--------0
 
1  -----1 --------------1-------------2-----------b---------9--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------1-------------3-----------d---------2--------0 
 
1  -----1 --------------1-------------8-----------e---------4--------1 
1  -----1 --------------1-------------2-----------b---------9--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------1-------------3-----------d---------2--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------1-------------8-----------e---------4--------1 
1  -----1 --------------1-------------2-----------b---------9--------0

1  -----1 --------------2-------------3-----------d---------2--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------2-------------8-----------e---------4--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------2-------------3-----------d---------2--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------2-------------8-----------e---------4--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------2-------------3-----------d---------2--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------2-------------8-----------e---------4--------1

1  -----1 --------------3-------------3-----------d---------2--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------3-------------8-----------e---------4--------0 
 
1  -----1 --------------3-------------3-----------d---------2--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------3-------------8-----------e---------4--------0 
 
1  -----1 --------------3-------------3-----------d---------2--------1 
 
1  -----1 --------------3-------------8-----------e---------4--------0

Comment: SELECT student_id FROM table WHERE cleared=1 Also,dont break your back working so hard so find the answer.

Comment: @Mihai get it down as an answer, man, you could collect some easy 10 pts... ;)

Comment: Eh,you post it you have lower rep.

Comment: @Mihai naa, not gonna take credit for something you said... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following

If the cleared Field type is 'text' then:---

```
SELECT student_id FROM batch_1_student_marks WHERE cleared='1';
```

If the cleared Field type is 'number' then:---

```
SELECT student_id FROM batch_1_student_marks WHERE cleared=1;
```

I hope that it will help you.

Comment: Rahul Goyal pls understand the question. In the above example there are 2 rows which are having student id '1' . In the first row cleared status is 0 and in the second row cleared status is 1. If the student_id is having the cleared status 0 in even single row. i dont want to select or consider the student_id. Even same student_id is having the cleared status 1 in next upcoming rows. i dont want to consider that student_id.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following query:

```
SELECT student_id FROM batch_1_student_marks WHERE cleared='1';
```

Comment: In the above example there are 2 rows which are having student id '1' . In the first row cleared status is 0 and in the second row cleared status is 1. If the student_id is having the cleared status 0 in even single row. i dont want to select or consider the student_id. Even same student_id is having the cleared status 1 in next upcoming rows. i dont want to consider that student_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student_id,cleared from batch_1_student_marks
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT cleared)=1
AND cleared=1
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a32fe/1)

You should have added the details from the start.A clear question almost answers itself.

Comment: this query is selecting student_id 1 and 2,3.but i dont want to select student_id 1 and 3 because it has cleared status 0